# show icon on certain value of progress bar with javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

I want to show my icon when value of my progress bar come to `15` and less with javascript:

My `progress` bar:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{($discount->products->stock * 100)/$discount->stock}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{($discount->products->stock * 100)/$discount->stock}}%;">
    {{$discount->products->stock}} remained
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flash-sale-progress-bar__fire"></div>
```

I want `<div class="flash-sale-progress-bar__fire"></div>` shows only when my value is equal to `15` until `0`.

`screenshot`

[image: screen]

Comment: @Callam yes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Blade directives, you can construct an if statement.

```
@if($discount->products->stock > 0 && $discount->products->stock <= 15)
    <div class="flash-sale-progress-bar__fire"></div>
@endif
```

Comment: I changed it to `@if($discount->products->stock > 0 && $discount->products->stock <= 15)` and it works now